# Display Validation Error for Inline Editing

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, error-messages

I have an LWC with a lightning-datatable that allows for inline editing.  If the field update violates a validation error, how do I display that specific validation error.  I conole.logged the error which shows the following:

```
{"status":400,"body":{"message":"An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.","statusCode":400,"enhancedErrorType":"RecordError","output":{"errors":[],"fieldErrors":{"End_Date__c":[{"constituentField":null,"duplicateRecordError":null,"errorCode":"FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION","field":"End_Date__c","fieldLabel":"End Date","message":"You cannot use the 1st of the month as an end date.  If the group structure is ending, use the final date of the month prior."}]}}},"headers":{}}
```

I can get the error.body.messgage to display but I have been unsuccessful in getting "You cannot use the 1st of the month as an end date.  If the group structure is ending, use the final date of the month prior." to display in the Toast Message.

Is there any way to actually display that portion of the error in the toast message?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lwc-recipe has an example utility to display errors under [ldsUtils](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils/ldsUtils.js). This is just an example of the benefit of one, but it doesn't handle your scenario (just exports `message` vs. looking at `enhancedErrorType`).

There's a great example of an improved util for reducing errors in tsalb's [lwc-utils repo](https://github.com/tsalb/lwc-utils) under [baseUtils.js](https://github.com/tsalb/lwc-utils/blob/master/utils-core/main/default/lwc/baseUtils/baseUtils.js). The below is taken from there and will display the message you'd like and is re-usable:

```
/**
 * Reduces one or more LDS errors into a string[] of error messages.
 * @param {FetchResponse|FetchResponse[]} errors
 * @return {String[]} Error messages
 */
const reduceErrors = errors => {
  if (!Array.isArray(errors)) {
    errors = [errors];
  }

  return (
    errors
      // Remove null/undefined items
      .filter(error => !!error)
      // Extract an error message
      .map(error => {
        // UI API read errors
        if (Array.isArray(error.body)) {
          return error.body.map(e => e.message);
        }
        // FIELD VALIDATION, FIELD, and trigger.addError
        else if (
          error.body &&
          error.body.enhancedErrorType &&
          error.body.enhancedErrorType.toLowerCase() === 'recorderror' &&
          error.body.output
        ) {
          let firstError = '';
          if (
            error.body.output.errors.length &&
            error.body.output.errors[0].errorCode.includes('_') // one of the many salesforce errors with underscores
          ) {
            firstError = error.body.output.errors[0].message;
          }
          if (!error.body.output.errors.length && error.body.output.fieldErrors) {
            // It's in a really weird format...
            firstError = error.body.output.fieldErrors[Object.keys(error.body.output.fieldErrors)[0]][0].message;
          }
          return firstError;
        }
        // UI API DML, Apex and network errors
        else if (error.body && typeof error.body.message === 'string') {
          let errorMessage = error.body.message;
          if (typeof error.body.stackTrace === 'string') {
            errorMessage += `\n${error.body.stackTrace}`;
          }
          return errorMessage;
        }
        // PAGE ERRORS
        else if (error.body && error.body.pageErrors.length) {
          return error.body.pageErrors[0].message;
        }
        // JS errors
        else if (typeof error.message === 'string') {
          return error.message;
        }
        // Unknown error shape so try HTTP status text
        return error.statusText;
      })
      // Flatten
      .reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr), [])
      // Remove empty strings
      .filter(message => !!message)
  );
};
```

Using the above with your error message returns the desired output within an array (in case of multiple errors) as demonstrated in this [playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/xrR1Zu1cfRqrzHvXXT6P):

> You cannot use the 1st of the month as an end date.  If the group structure is ending, use the final date of the month prior.

Comment: awesome references, wasn't aware they existed +1

Answer (score 1):

Considering that your Json is as follows:

```
{
    "status": 400,
    "body": {
        "message": "An error occurred while trying to update the record. Please try again.",
        "statusCode": 400,
        "enhancedErrorType": "RecordError",
        "output": {
            "errors": [],
            "fieldErrors": {
                "End_Date__c": [{
                    "constituentField": null,
                    "duplicateRecordError": null,
                    "errorCode": "FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION",
                    "field": "End_Date__c",
                    "fieldLabel": "End Date",
                    "message": "You cannot use the 1st of the month as an end date.  If the group structure is ending, use the final date of the month prior."
                }]
            }
        }
    },
    "headers": {}
}
```

you would/could find a way to access the message property under the field name:

simple test would be to try out:

```
body.output.fieldErrors.End_Date__c[0].message
```

and from there figure out a way to make it dynamic, in case the fieldName is different,

for example:

```
body.output.fieldErrors.[fieldName][0].message
```

you can then concatenate the string(s) to form 1 error message.